# Jasmine - Unable to get response of an async call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am facing an issue when unit testing my AngularJS service using Jasmine. This is the test case which is causing the issue:

```
describe( '#getData', function () {
    it( 'Gets the data', function ( done ) {
        var promise = service.getData();
        $rootScope.$apply();
        console.log( promise );

        promise.then( function ( resp ) {
            expect( resp ).toEqual( mockData );
            done();
        } ).catch( function () {
            done();
        } ).finally( function () {
            done();
        } );
    } );
} );
```

This is pretty straight forward. I'm trying to test the method `getData` of the `service`. All the variables are in-place and there are no console errors.

The statement `console.log( promise )` prints something like this on the console:

```
Promise{$$state: Object{status: 1, value: Object{status: ..., data: ...}}}
```

Which means that `promise` is a valid Promise object. But the issue here is that I am not able to test the data returned by this promise. When I call `then` on the promise object and call `done` function in any of the handlers (`then`, `catch`, or `finally`), the control doesn't go in any one of them and the test runner times out.

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

I tried to increase the default timeout as well, but that makes the test skipped. On the other hand, if I try to execute this case synchronously (without using `done`), it passes successfully.

How can I test the response in the test case asynchronously?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to transform "it" function handler into an async function? You can use await to get the service.getData() response and then make the validation. Please let me know.

Comment: @LuizDuarte -- I cannot use `async/await` due to the tech limitations in the code. Can you post an answer with the _transformed `it`_ function but without using async/await?

Comment: Ok, I thought somehow you'd be able to transpile it to ES5... Well, by that... What's the outcome from the console.log when you put it inside of Then/Catch (add an arg to get the err inside catch)? I'm asking because console.log will for sure return a Promise Pending status right after call it.

Comment: @LuizDuarte -- as I mentioned, the callbacks are executed at all. If I log something in `then` or `catch` or `finally`, nothing is logged and the test times out with an error `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`.

Comment: Ok... So mean, callbacks are NOT executed, right? Silly question but have you checked if the service.getData() is getting timedout? Can you post whatever it's doing?

Comment: Are you using `httpBackend`? if so, show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS was designed to be synchronous in tests, `done` is undesirable here.

`$q` promises depend on digests, promise chain won't be executed without a digest. A digest was triggered in wrong place, it should be:

```
it( 'Gets the data', function () {
    var promise = service.getData();

    promise.then( function ( resp ) {
        expect( resp ).toEqual( mockData );
    } ).catch( function (err) {
        throw err;
    } ));

    $rootScope.$apply();
} );
```

[`jasmine-promise-matchers`](https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers) can be recommended for `$q` promise assertions in Jasmine.

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. The point was to run the digest after we've bound promise callbacks.